# Failed to create SQLite3 database with file protection in iOS

Tags: ios, database, xcode, encryption, sqlite

**Background:** I have been watching through WWDC 2011 - 208 Securing iOS application. They mention about how to secure our data with file encryption called NSFileProtection. While I discover the [automatic method mentioned (@38:00) is bugged](https://devforums.apple.com/message/627887#627887), I hope the manual way (@37:00) is not. I tried using file protection with images and all is well. Only Sqlite I cannot create.

**Problem:** I try to create SQLite3 database (without core data) with `sqlite3_open_v2` and passing `SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_COMPLETE`as the flag for the third argument. It does not return `SQLITE_OK`.

**Code:**

```
if (sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_COMPLETE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
   //everything works
}else{
  //failed
}
```

---

**Update:**
As borrrden mentioned, both has resulted in the following error code:
`SQLITE_MISUSE` (Library used incorrectly)

---

**Update 2:**
borrrden's 2nd comment was correct to point out the need for both flags. It works following the code:

```
if (sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE|SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_COMPLETE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```

Comment: Just for fun, try `SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_COMPLETE|SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`  If that doesn't work, then post the error.  You will have to get it from the sqlite API.  If you don't know how to do that...then I'm afraid you have no business using sqlite yet.

Comment: @borrrden Thank you, I am relatively new to SQLite. I looked up the error code and updated my original question. Please have a look.

Comment: It means the parameter combination is invalid.  Looking at other sqlite examples, I think you also need to add `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` as well as `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`

Comment: @borrrden you were correct, please answer the question so I can mark it as answer. I also updated my question with your answer in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite is not happy about the lack of a file access mode being specified in your flags.  It doesn't know whether it should open it writable or not, or whether or not to create it if it does not exist.  Therefore, add the following two flags along with the one you are currently using:

> SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE
> SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE

This signals that sqlite should open a writable database, and create it if it does not exist.