# How to open sqlite database when app runs in background in ios

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

My application captures location data in background and saves in sqlite database. It works well when Device is not locked, but when device is locked I am not able to access sqlite database. It always gives me error code as SQLITE_AUTH(error code:23).
I have tried below options:

1. Disable the Data Protection from Capabilities.(Does not work)
2. As per [Failed to create SQLite3 database with file protection in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721350/failed-to-create-sqlite3-database-with-file-protection-in-ios), I tried the below code :

sqlite3_open_v2([dbPath UTF8String], &myDatabase, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE|SQLITE_OPEN_FILEPROTECTION_COMPLETE, NULL)

But still its not working.

Could you please help me, How to access the sqlite database in background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable [Data Protection](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) from your app from iTunesconnect.

**1. Enable data protection for your app**. For example,

[image]

**2. Add below [file protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfileprotectiontype?language=objc) key and value into your plist or entitlement file,**

```
<key>com.apple.developer.default-data-protection</key>
<string> NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication</string>
```

The type must match to your capability set from itunes server.

**3. Rebuild and test if the issue is resolved**

---

<sup>**File Data Protection**
In addition to the hardware encryption features built into iOS devices, Apple
uses a technology called Data Protection to further protect data stored in flash
memory on the device. Data Protection allows the device to respond to common
events such as incoming phone calls, but also enables a high level of encryption
for user data. Key system apps, such as Messages, Mail, Calendar, Contacts,
Photos, and Health data values use Data Protection by default, and third-party
apps installed on iOS 7 or later receive this protection automatically.
Data Protection is implemented by constructing and managing a hierarchy
of keys, and builds on the hardware encryption technologies built into each
iOS device. Data Protection is controlled on a per-file basis by assigning each
file to a class; accessibility is determined by whether the class keys have been
unlocked. With the advent of the Apple File System (APFS), the file system is
now able to further sub-divide the keys into a per-extent basis (portions of a
file can have different keys). Find detail here in section [File Data Protection](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf).</sup>